# Data Encoding and Decoding

Tags: c#, encoding, serial-port, extract, decoding

I do have an Encoding function that create me a Command, 
I Assume I'm having an Output in Byte String like (0010010210004443331012011101000)

I do need to create Decode Function to Extract Some Data From This Byte Lets say from position 8 until 12 And after Extract this Check IF the first byte of Array is 00 or Not Then Return me Extract Data in ASCII

Here is my Decode

Here is My Decode that is Totally Wrong

```
public byte[] Decode(string Resp)
{

    string NewResp = Resp;
        string SubResp = NewResp.Substring(65, 185);
        Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", SubResp);

        MessageBox.Show(SubResp);
    return null;
}
```

Here is Encode

```
 {


        return bCommand;
    }
```

Comment: well, do u have the encode algo?

Comment: yes i do have Encode i added there

Comment: why NewResp.Substring(65, 185); <-- i dont get this part?

Comment: as i am assuming u need the bytes from 8th to 12th position from encoded byte right? and perform a comparision against that ?

Comment: Yes that what i need and also i need to check value position 6,7 and 13 Also . Im not quiet Sure how im going to do this as My Decode should be in Byte[] and also the final result should be in ASCII format.

Comment: so u need to make sure byte at 6,7,8 and 13th are not \0 ?

Comment: if (encoded[5] != '\0' && encoded[6] != '\0' && encoded[12] != '\0')
            {
                // validated ?
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] encoded =
                {
                    0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x24, 0x02, 0x43, 0x31, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x43, 0x49, 0x53, 0x2D,
                    0x34, 0x36, 0x58, 0x58, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x11
                };

            byte[] toCheck = SubArray<byte>(encoded, 8, 5); // start index at 8 and u need till 12th

            if (toCheck[0] != '\0')
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(toCheck));
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        public static T[] SubArray<T>(T[] data, int index, int length)
        {
            T[] result = new T[length];
            Array.Copy(data, index, result, 0, length);
            return result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How Can i Separate This? This Encode\ and Decode should be Modular and Call from Outside of Function  should be Construct

Answer (score -1):

You have hexstring like

```
string hexstr= "68696d616e736875";
string subHexstr= hexstr.Substring(2,3); // Lets say index from 3rd byte to 5th byte.
byte[] by=new byte[subHexstr.Length];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < by.Length; i++)
        {
            by[i] = byte.Parse(subHexstr.Substring(j, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            j = j + 2;
        }

if(by[0]!=0x00)
{ 
  string asciiStr= Encoding.Ascii.GetString(by);
}
```